# Oracle Apex : Showing SQL Count beside Navigation Menu Icon and Text

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want a dynamic number (an output of SQL query) to be shown besides page link text and icon in the navigation menu of my Oracle Apex application (Just the way it has been done in Oracle Apex Opportunity Tracker sample application).

Editing the static text of link is really simple and can be done by going to ****Application123\Shared Components\Lists**** and editing **Application Menu** but what I don't know is that how can I display a count there besides the Text and icon.

This is the desired output [image]

This is where I know, I can edit the text (static) and change/select the icon for the link [image]
but where to write SQL query and get its result instead of [&Leads.] , that's is not in my knowledge. Really appreciate help on this !!!!

```
select count(mycolumnname)
from mytablename
where anotherdatecolumn = trunc(current_date)  and (referid='1' or referid='12' or referidD='18');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `DEALS` should be an **application item** (declared in Shared Components)
- query should be then used in **application computations** (also in Shared Components)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I created an APPLICATION ITEM and created APPLICATION COMPUTATION selecting the very same item with above given query set as SQL QUERY (return single value). Changed the Application Menu item with [&myitemname.] but no numbers shows in the notification above the icon+text link in application's navigation menu. Any idea on what could be the reason?

Comment: You're welcome. Well, it woks in my application (I'm on Apex 18.2). Are you sure that query returns some value? Did you test it in e.g. SQL*Plus?

Comment: It actually works. My bad, I had computation point set as "on new instance/session" and was testing it within the same session, started new session and its displaying the value of query correctly. Thank you once again for directing me to the desired outcome.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if it helped.

Comment: Indeed it helped really well :)